# In nuget, how can I achieve the equivalent of maven's "starter" poms?

Tags: nuget

One thing that was great in maven was the ability to use the dependency management tags to make a pom.xml that specified what versions of dependencies to use. So when you made that a dependency and didn't include the exact versions of your other dependencies, it would use all the versions specified in your starter. This way you could have one pom of all the versions of your dependencies that are compatible with each other and tested. While still letting your modules only include the dependencies they actually needed.

Is there a way to accomplish this in nuget?
I was thinking of making a nuget that has all the dependencies with their versions in it to then have all the modules dependent on the one nuget. However, that would then make every independent module now have all the nuget packages instead of just the ones it needs.

Thanks in advance!